# C# Recursion, Calling other method from recursive method return wrong Value

Tags: c#, recursion

This is my code

```
private double wordcompare(word a, word b)
{    
     if (a.AtTheEndOf(b))
         return -1;
     double matchPer=word.Compare( a,b);
     Console.WriteLine(matchPer);
     a.shiftToleft();
     double nextMatchPer = wordcompare(a, b);
     return matchPer > nextMatchPer ? matchPer : nextMatchPer;
}
```

the Compare() method compare 2 words and return a percentage of match letters 
the shifttoleft() method move the compared word one step virtually,
I have been debugged every step when it arrives to the return of Compare() there is numbers like 2/3 or 1/3 but when but when i print the returned value it shows 0 except the first call help please.

word class

```
class word
{
    public static double Pertolarnce = 0.2;

    private int pos;
    public int wordTolarnce;
    string letters;

    public int Pos {  get{ return pos; }  }
    public word(string s)
    {
        letters = s;
        wordTolarnce=(int)Math.Round(Pertolarnce * s.Length, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) ;
        pos = 0 - wordTolarnce;
    }


    public void shiftToleft()
    {
        pos++;
    }

    public int Len { get { return letters.Length; } }

    public static double Compare(word a,word w)
    {
        int comLeters = 0;
        int matchedLeters = 0;
        int i, j;
        i = 0 - a.pos;
        j = 0 + a.pos;
        i=i < 0 ? 0 : i;
        j=j < 0 ? 0 : j;
        while(i<a.Len && j<w.Len )
        {
            comLeters++;
            if (a.letters[i] == w.leterAt(j))
                matchedLeters++;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        return matchedLeters / comLeters;
    }

    private char leterAt(int index)
    {
        return letters[index];
    }

    public bool AtTheEndOf(word w)
    {
        if(w.Len-this.pos+1 == this.Len-wordTolarnce)
        return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

output of

```
    Console.WriteLine(matchPer);
    1
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results for those sample inputs.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We don't know what `shiftToLeft` does, or `wordcompare`, or how you're calling the method, or what result you expect, or what result you get. I'd also very strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Your `wordcompare` method appears to change the `a` object, this is really not a good idea. A comparison method should ideally be pure, ie. it takes input, it returns a result based on that input, and doesn't modify anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is integer division. `matchedLeters / comLeters` will perform integer division which means that any remainder is discarded. That means that if `matcheLeters` is less than `comLeters` that you will get 0 returned as you saw.

To fix this you can do the following:

```
return (double)matchedLeters / comLeters;
```

This will cast `matchedLeters` to a double before the division which will force it to use floating point division instead.

As a debugging tip you might have got more of an idea of the problem if you'd done (for debugging):

```
var retVal = matchedLeters/comLeters;
return retVal;
```

This would have allowed you to see exactly what operation was causing you the problem.